# Merging Core Data NSManagedObjectContexts in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am using the "old-school" Core Data concurrency model. In other words, I have a main `NSManagedObjectContext` that is created with `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` and any network requests process JSON response data in a freshly created `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` context. The contexts share a `persistentStoreCoordinator` instead of using a `parentContext` and context merging is done manually.

Since iOS 8, *some* of my devices have exhibited a behavior that seems context merging is not working correctly. After observing a `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`, I am merging changes into my main context by calling `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` on my main context. Afterwards, I attempt to grab the main context versions of the active object graph with `objectWithID:` which superficially appears to work. However, upon close inspection of the objects returned, any `NSSet` relationships are empty even though the secondary context version has them.*

Oddly, the same code produces accurate context merging on an iPhone 6/6+ running iOS 8. Even my iOS 7 iPod Touch 5G works correctly. The device that consistently fails is an identical iOS 8 iPod Touch 5G. It works in all simulators as well.

Has anyone else seen a similar behavior or have insight as to what might cause this device-specific Core Data issue? Thanks in advance.

```
__block id toReturn = [self processResponse:responseData]; //Complete object graph from api.

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
[context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[self persistentStoreCoordinator]]; //shared PSC
[context setUndoManager:nil];
[context setStalenessInterval:0];
[context setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];

NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [self mainContext];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                                   object:context
                                                    queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                               usingBlock:
            ^(NSNotification *notification) {
              [mainContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
              NSManagedObjectID *managedId = [toReturn objectID];
              NSManagedObject *mainContextVersion = [mainContext objectWithID:managedId];
              toReturn = mainContextVersion; //*This is where the object graph is incomplete
            }];

//Save context, will fire NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification.
NSError *errorWhileSaving;
[context save:&errorWhileSaving];
```

Comment: Your first paragraph outlines your issue well. It's not device specific, it has everything to do with using queue confinement and merge notifications - they don't work well together, and if you are using performBlockAndWait you are going to have very difficult to diagnose problems due to the lack of user event processing.

Comment: I am not using `performBlockAndWait.` Do you mean "aren't using" @quellish? If so, I was under the impression I only needed to use `performBlock` or `performBlockAndWait` if I was using the parent-child context model since `save` is a synchronous event and the notification only fires after the save is complete. In any case, I have tried wrapping both the `save` and the `mergeChanges...` calls in `performBlockAndWait` blocks with no change in result.

Comment: I meant "are". If you are using contexts that were created with anything but `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` you must use the block methods to access any part of the context, including it's objects and their properties, with the exception of the context's own accessor methods.

Answer (score 1):

I would not play the game you appear to be playing with `toReturn` where it looks like it starts out as a managed object in the private context, and becomes a managed object in the main context.

You should use a managed object ID as the global block variable (or, better yet, no global at all) so you don't have to peek into the managed object to get it.  I've seen a number of claims that you can get the ObjectID without using `performBlock` but I never touch any MO/MOC outside its `performBlock`.  Never.  Ever.  Too many headaches in the past, so I just stick to my guns.

```
__block NSManagedObjectID *toReturnObjectID;
```

However, if you want to do that, you must access it from the proper context first.  At first blush, something like this... which is very ugly, but demonstrates the point...

```
[mainContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
[toReturn.context performBlock: ^{
    NSManagedObjectID *managedId = [toReturn objectID];
    [mainContext performBlock: ^{
        NSManagedObject *mainContextVersion = [mainContext objectWithID:managedId];
        toReturn = mainContextVersion; //*This is where the object graph is incomplete
        // All the rest of the code that needs to happen...
```

Note, also, that any access of your global `toReturn` after calling save in the other context could spell trouble.  Basically, you should not do that.  You already fire a notification when processing is complete.  Why not put the `toReturn` in the notification user info, rather than piling it into a global variable?  Also, you could put the ObjectID in the userInfo of the context posting the did-save notification, and grab it out of there when the notification is fired.

If you let the notification run in its own thread (not give a queue for the block to run on), you can access the saving MOC because you are running in its active thread/queue/context.  Shove the object ID into the userInfo before saving.

Something like...

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    addObserverForName:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                object:context
                 queue:nil
            usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification) {
        // we can access the context here, since we are running in its notification
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [notification object];
        NSManagedObjectID *managedId = [[context userInfo] objectForKey:@"ObjectGraphOID"];
        // Now that we have the object ID, capture it in the block that will do the work...
        [mainContext performBlock:^{
            [mainContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
            NSManagedObject *mainContextVersion = [mainContext objectWithID:managedId];

            NSMutableDictionary *mainContextUserInfo =
                [[self migratedInsertedObjectsDictionaryFromUserInfo:[notification userInfo]] mutableCopy];

            // Pass the result as part of userInfo of the notification
            mainContextUserInfo[@"ObjectGraph"] = mainContextVersion;
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
                postNotificationName:FPFlatpackCycleCompleted
                              object:self
                            userInfo:mainContextUserInfo];
        }];
    }];
```